# Centering in css

Tags: css, html, center

I am trying to center a div that wil constantly appear when scrolling. How shall I center it because I have tried all the methods I've seen and none appear to work.
Here is the code:

```
#header {
position:fixed;
top:0%;
left:0%;
height:100px;
width:100%;
}

<div id='header'>
<button class='butt'>Home</button>
<button class='butt'>Home</button>
<img id='logo' src='Website/GUGM still logo.png' />         <!--Header That Moves-->
<button class='butt'>Home</button>
<button class='butt'>Home</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways depending on the behavior of your header.

If your header has a fixed width, set the `left` and `right` properties to `zero` and set the left and right `margin` to `auto`: http://jsfiddle.net/YHrUm/

```
div {
    background:red;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    height:50%;
    width:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

If your header has a percentage width, you just need to set the `left` and `right` properties to the proper percentage. For example if your header will be `80%` of the width you do this: http://jsfiddle.net/YHrUm/1/

```
div {
    background:red;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:10%;
    right:10%;
    height:50%;
}
```

But if your header has `100%` width then you might want to center the content instead, which you do with `text-align:center` like everyone else said.

**EDIT**

A little extra: The trick with `left` and `right` and `auto` also works for `top` and `bottom`. You just need to apply the `auto` to the correct `margin`.

Comment: You are a genius. Thank you so much you have saved my project! I only had to change some properties and thank you for explaining it so well.

Answer (score 0):

Normal methods to center:

```
text-align: center;
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/T8R9P/)

And

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

As you have `width: 100%;`, `margin: 0 auto;` will not work. This will center a `div` (or others) but as yours is `100%` it cant center it as in a way it already is. So instead you can center the content.

Answer (score 0):

add `text-align:center` to the header, and for all elements inside add `display:inline-block`

Comment: images and buttons are both inline elements by default. Whats the purpose of adding inline-block to all the elements inside ?